Median calculation of IFS function returns #VALUE! error
I need to calculate the median number of construction days for multiple projects across multiple markets and based on whether the project is completed or not.
Examples

ROW A = Markets
ROW B = Days in Construction
ROW C = Status (P=Pending A=Completed)

I am using table references and my formula below returns a #VALUE! error:
=MEDIAN(
  IFS(
   [@Market], Details[Market Combined],
   Details[On-Air S]="P", Details[Current Days Count CXs to Today]))

enter image description here

My answer below could be improved if you shared some sample data in text format.  Your example uses Rows (columns?) but your formula uses structured table references. That, combined with a lack of sample data, makes it difficult to know if there is just one issue or more.

If the value in [@Market] is a text string, that is why you are getting the #VALUE! error.
The examples below hold true for both IF and IFS:
=IF(44, true, false)          // non-zero numbers 
=TRUE                         // are always TRUE

=IF("Bob", true, false)       // Text is not a condition
=#VALUE!                      // (except true/false) 

=IF("true", true, false)      // true/false text is valid
=TRUE                            

=IF("Bob"<>"", true, false)   // valid condition
=TRUE

=IF(LEN("Bob"), true, false)  // valid condition that 
=TRUE                         // evaluates to 0 or non-zero number


The "Market" column does have text in it.  I've tried to index and match, but not coming up with the correct numbers.
=MEDIAN(IF(Details[On-Air S]="P",INDEX(Details[Current Days Count CXs to Today],MATCH([@Market],Details[Market Combined],0))))

@RichardTurner As I noted on your question, please add some sample data for all your fields to the question and this can be resolved quickly.

Added a snippet above.  I created a column in another table where I want to figure the Median for Construction Start (CXs) to today.  Snippet is currently filtered to "P" in the On-Air S column, there are "A"s as well, but I currently only need the median for "P"s.
